# Separate key-values in a dictionary and recreate the dict after processing the values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dictionary like this:

```
{'T096': ['AABBAACACCAADBAACCAAAACACCBBAE'],
'T122': ['AACAABBBCABBDAACABCACABBAAACCCCAE'],
'T154': ['ABAABDBAAACCCAE'],
'T169': ['CCDBAACCAAAACCAE'],
'T176': ['BDACACCAAAACCCCAE'],
'T183': ['BBAACAACCBDAACBACCCCAAAACCAE'],
'T197': ['AABBAACABABACABAAABDBAAACCAE'],
'T178': ['CACDBAAACCCAE'],
'T067': ['BACAACCDBAABACCACCAAABCCACACCCCAE']}
```

I use a library that accepts a list of strings and does some processing (in this example generates common prefixes). 
So I extract all values from the above dict.
Once the processing is done (in this example I get the prefixes), I am interested in assigning those processed strings (here, common prefixes) back to the keys in the dict. 
E.g. something like this:

```
{'T096': ['AAB'],
'T197': ['AAB']}  # in the rest, there are no common prefixes, so ignored, or set to None
```

Now I need to be able to retain the mapping between the keys and values, even after extracting all the values. Is there a way to do that elegantly?

Edit: Replaced "get prefix" with "string processing" to reflect the broader scope of the problem!

Comment: Common prefixes between the values of the dictionary?

Comment: So, you are looking for Keys in a Dictionary who has same prefix?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Yes, common prefixes among the values of the dictionary (There is more processing done later, this is the first step, so cannot use Austin's answer below)

Comment: @pygo I need to track the key: prefix (in the example I have just one common prefix, there could be many, so I should be able to track all of them)

Comment: I am wondering if using `collections.OrderdDict` to store and use the key - value later to combine helps, since list order is maintained among the 2 lists?

Comment: @okkhoy,  Thats what i'm saying, you are sorting by value as a prefix not Key..

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary-comprehension with `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {'T096': ['AABBAACACCAADBAACCAAAACACCBBAE'],
'T122': ['AACAABBBCABBDAACABCACABBAAACCCCAE'],
'T154': ['ABAABDBAAACCCAE'],
'T169': ['CCDBAACCAAAACCAE'],
'T176': ['BDACACCAAAACCCCAE'],
'T183': ['BBAACAACCBDAACBACCCCAAAACCAE'],
'T197': ['AABBAACABABACABAAABDBAAACCAE'],
'T178': ['CACDBAAACCCAE'],
'T067': ['BACAACCDBAABACCACCAAABCCACACCCCAE']}

c = Counter(x[0][:3] for x in d.values())
print({k: v[0][:3] for k, v in d.items() if c[v[0][:3]] > 1})

# {'T096': 'AAB', 'T197': 'AAB'}
```

Comment: Sorry for misleading you to this solution, it is not just a prefix, I do a bunch of processing using the list of strings (in this example it was finding prefix) so I can't use `collections.Counter`. Edited the original post.

Comment: @okkhoy, still broad! What are those bunch of operations?